# Recursive Feature Elimination (RFE) with Logistic Regression and little correlation between the features and the target (SKLearn)

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, logistic-regression

I have little experience in the field of Machine Learning, so I apologise in advance for my ignorance and lack of intuitions.

I'm trying to build a classifying algorithm to identify if a subject is healthy or ill. I have the following data:

- 17 subjects.
- Each subject has 1140 features, ranging from -1 to 1.
- Each subject has a label from 0 to 6. 0 meaning very ill and 6 completely healthy.
- I only have data of subjects with labels from 0 to 2.
- The features (X) have low correlation with the labels (Y).

The way I obtained the features is irrelevant to this question, so I'm not going to go through it.

This is how the data looks:

[image]

Each colour represents a subject. As I have mentioned, I only have data of subjects with labels from 0 to 2, that is, Y=0, Y=1 or Y=2. And the features (X) are then 17 Subjects x 1140 features.

What I want to do is the following:

- Fit the data into a Logistic Regression.
- Use the Recursive Feature Elimination algorithm in order to fit the data into the classification function and know how many features I need to select so that its accuracy is high.
- Use Stratified Cross Validation to enhance the accuracy.

This is how I've implemented the algorithm in Python.

```
skf = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=50, test_size=0.3) # Cross-validation 50 times
estimator = LogisticRegression(C=1) # The estimator used is Logistic Regression
selector = RFECV(estimator, step=1, cv=skf, scoring="accuracy") # Run RFE
selector = selector.fit(X, Y) # Fit the data
print(selector.grid_scores_) # Print accuracy
```

And I obtained an accuracy around 60% for all the features, as shown below:

[image]

So, my question is. Do you think I implemented the code in the right way? Do you have any suggestion to enhance the accuracy? Maybe adjust a bit the parameters?

Thanks a lot. I hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you think I implemented the code in the right way?

Code is correct, but he is minimal possible.

> The features (X) have low correlation with the labels (Y).

It's could be the biggest problem, features have to have correlation with labels.

> Do you have any suggestion to enhance the accuracy?

- Make transformation of labels(X). Preparing of labels its one most important parts in Machine Learning. Please read data transformation or feature extraction.
- After this try different algorithms like xgboost, adaboost, random forest etc.
- Perhaps you should use regularization L1 or L2.
- Try early stopping.
- After this step use cross-validation.
- Choose suitable metrics for yours problem.